# AFP can't write because of locked volume

Tags: network, permission, sharing, afp

I'm trying to write contents to my shared folders on my Raspberry Pi over AFP.
However I keep getting the same error/warning regarding permissions and locked volume:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm fairly sure permissions are right, I'm logged and as the default pi user and used `chown -R pi /mnt/seagate` on the pi to own my HDD mount for the pi user.
This didn't work so I tried setting permissions for my /var/www folder with `chmod -R 777 /var/www`, resulting in the same error pictured above.

Checking the permissions in the Finder for the home folder (which should be no issue, being logged in as the pi user) I see that everyone has RW permissions.

[image: screen]
[image: screen]

I think the issue isn't my pi's fault (hence why I posted this here and not on raspberrypi). I think there must be something wrong with my AFP configuration on my Mac (also note that I used this method of sharing folders from pi with AFP to mac before and it always worked before).
I attached a screenshot of my afp configuration below since I have no clue what could be wrong. If needed to help, I can also provide the configurations for netatalk (afp protocol on the pi).

[image: afp_conf_screen]

Answer (score 1):

Probably some permissions and/or the settings are set wrong on your Raspberry.
I suspect the external drive or a shared folder on the external drive to have wrong permissions set. Compare that with the your home folder on the Raspberry where you probably have full r/w access.

Please try this as a first step. You may apply special settings/configs later.
Below i assume that your external disk is sdb and contains one ext4 volume sdb1 with the name seagate. The volume/partition itself should **not** be owned by pi but by root!

First stop netatalk with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/netatalk stop
```

Unmount your external volume after checking the the mounted volumes with `df` or `cat /proc/mounts` to get the identifier of your external disk:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

First we have to fix your mount point:

The following permissions should apply (check this with `ls -la` on the Raspberry):

For /mnt

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr  6 13:52 mnt
```

Check that the folder /mnt contains a folder seagate with `ls -la`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr  6 13:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Apr  6 11:21 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Apr  6 14:14 seagate
```

Add the folder if necessary with `sudo mkdir /mnt/seagate` and change permissions and ownership accordingly with chown and chmod.

Get the UUID of all volumes with `sudo blkid`. You should get a similar output like that one:

```
/dev/sda5: UUID="7a7dd5de-758e-4488-b78d-dd7f7c61cfbc" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="9b4285a8-3290-469a-91f3-7517f286856e" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="seagate" UUID="522e7f4c-ee90-4265-82c1-e46f48f969b5" TYPE="ext4"
```

sda1 and sda5 are your internal main and swap partition. sdb1 is the first volume on your external disk.

Check with `sudo nano /etc/fstab` if your fstab file mounts the volume of the external disk at /mnt/seagate. Replace the UUIDs below with those found in your setup.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=9b4285a8-3290-469a-91f3-7517f286856e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=7a7dd5de-758e-4488-b78d-dd7f7c61cfbc none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
UUID=522e7f4c-ee90-4265-82c1-e46f48f969b5" /mnt/seagate/     ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Remount sdb1 with `sudo mount /dev/sdb1` and check the mountpoint with `df`. It should look like this:

```
...
...
/dev/sdb1   8256916  170156   7667332    3% /mnt/seagate
```

Now create a base folder for the user pi:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/seagate/pi
```

Move all your personal folders to pi with:

```
sudo mv /mnt/seagate/folder sudo mv /mnt/seagate/pi/folder
```

Example:

```
sudo mv "/mnt/seagate/Film - 1" "/mnt/seagate/pi/Film - 1"
```

Then apply ownership recursively with

```
sudo chown -R pi:pi /mnt/seagate/pi
```

Reapply ownership and permissions of /mnt/seagate/lost+found with

```
sudo chown -R root:root /mnt/seagate/lost+found
sudo chmod 700 /mnt/seagate/lost+found
```

Now you have to check netatalk and fix it if necessary:

Locate the following startup options and change them as noted below in /etc/default/netatalk with `sudo nano /etc/default/netatalk`:

```
ATALKD_RUN=no
PAPD_RUN=no
CNID_METAD_RUN=yes
AFPD_RUN=yes
TIMELORD_RUN=no
A2BOOT_RUN=no
```

Go to the end of the file /etc/netatalk/afpd.conf. It should look similar to this:

```
# default:
- -tcp -noddp -uamlist uams_dhx.so,uams_dhx2.so -nosavepassword
```

Now configure the shared volumes in /etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default near the end of the file:

```
~/              "Home Directory"
/mnt/seagate/pi "pi-seagate" allow:pi
```

The first is the directory to share, the second is the name visible in the "Connect to Server" -> "Volumes to select" window and later on your desktop and the third is/are the allowed user(s).

Restart netatalk with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/netatalk start
```

Try to connect to the share(s) with your Mac OS X 10.10 client by entering: "afp://ip-address" in 'Go to...' -> 'Connect to Server'.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow (I completely reinstalled my Raspbian), though I think I found a lead on the issue. While trying to remove a file on /mnt/seagate with `rm file.txt` I got the following notice on my pi: `rm: remove write-protected regular file 'file.txt'?`. Could it be an issue with the HDD being locked? Only with sudo can I remove this file.

Comment: I got output which shows the dialout group when I run ls -l for the mount point (I mounted on /home/pi/mounts/seagate now): http://imgur.com/WDKo2ch.png

Comment: @Thibmaekelbergh I have updated my answer to hopefully fix all issues. Please stick with my proposals since i can't foresee any changes you make to mount points and your personal folders. You may apply changes (like different mount points) later.

Comment: permissions were indeed wrong but I think the issue was something odd with netatalk. I switched to SMB with same permissions and it did work now.

Comment: @Thibmaekelbergh I have a tested all this in a VM (a lightweight Debian as Raspberry), a real 10.7 client and a virtual 10.10 client and it works without any problem.